# Parameter not set error in Prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to execute a prepared statement in JDBC, and everytime I execute it I get the error message "Paramater not set".
I have tried repeatedly to check for unset parameters - but I only have the one. This leads me to believe it is another foolish error on my part.

If you could point this out to me, I would be very grateful

```
public book search(String key){
        book temp = null;

        try {
            String stmt = "SELECT BookID, Title, Author, Media, Available FROM BOOK WHERE Title LIKE ?;"; 
            connection = DatabaseConnection(); 
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement(stmt); 
            System.out.println(key);
            preparedStmt.setObject(1, key);//the name
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(stmt); //Using Prepared Statements prepare the query

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(); //Execute the query



            while (resultSet.next()) {

                int bookID = resultSet.getInt("BookID");//Get the userName
                String title = resultSet.getString("Title"); //Get the score
                String author = resultSet.getString("Author"); //Get the score
                String media = resultSet.getString("Media"); //Get the score
                boolean available = resultSet.getBoolean("Available"); //Get the score

                temp = new book(title,author,media,available,bookID);


            }
            connection.close(); //close connection


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception!");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }



        return temp;


    }
```

Comment: Unrelated but: it's better to use the `setXXX()` method that corresponds to the actual data type. `setObject()` might not always work as expected. So in your case use `setString(1, key)` that will be much more reliable.

Answer (score 6):

You're calling `prepareStatement` twice, setting the parameter on the first one but then calling `executeQuery` on the second.

It's not clear where you're event declaring `statement` or `resultSet`, but you want:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement(stmt); 
preparedStmt.setString(1, key);
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStmt.executeQuery();
```

Note that I've made `resultSet` a local variable - you really don't want it to be a field... there's also no reason for your `temp` variable as you can just return directly from the `while` loop. (I've changed the code to use `setString` instead of `setObject`, too...)

You should use try-with-resources statements to close both the statement and the result set automatically...)

Comment: Holy crap, can't believe I missed that! Thank you

Comment: If returning directly from the while loop, then try-with-resources should definitely be used in order to close the `Statement` and `Connection` properly upon exiting the method.